# How to separate symbols from string?

Tags: ruby

If I have a string that contains currency symbols how can I separate the symbol from the string? Assume the symbol could be anywhere in the string (ie. front, back, after a space)

```
"$5"      => "$", "5"
"50,000₩" => "₩", "50,000"
"€307"    => "€", "307"
```

Is this possible using regex? Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: How many symbols in a string? One or multiple?

Comment: Define what you mean by symbols.

Comment: There should not be more than one, but it could be almost anything.

Comment: @sawa it would likely be currency symbols.

Comment: Which country uses `@` (at each) for currency symbol?

Comment: @NigoroJr it comes in as a string

Comment: @sawa I don't believe any do, but it could be ANY currency, so I assumed removing all symbols would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this, but

```
str.scan(/\w/).join('')
```

will give you the alphanumeric characters, and

```
str.scan(/\W/).join('')
```

will give you the non-alphanumeric characters.

`\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `\W` is `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Since you have `"50,000₩" => "₩", "50,000"` in your example, you might want:

```
str.scan(/[a-zA-Z0-9_,]/).join('')
```

Also, if you know that you'll only have numbers, `str.gsub(/[^0-9,]/, '')` will probably do fine.

Comment: That will do the job. Thank you for the suggestion.